# ServicePrincipleName setup for Web Service on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis-7, active-directory

I'm so confused.

Consider the following:

- Active Directory environment with a domain called DOM
- An IIS 7 box with a NetBIOS name VS1
- A DNS record providing an alias for VS1 as pineapple.london.uk.corp
- An Application Pool running as DOM\PineappleService
- Windows Authentication enabled.
- Clients use HttpWebRequest to call the XML/JSON ASP.NET services on the box.

The service calls out to workstations on the network to gather information. This works in development where I use IIS Express which runs as me, since IISX is just an .exe

In production, services work fine, authentication works, but invoking functions that cause the service (running as PineappleService) to access stuff on the network, fails.

I suspect an SPN registration issue but I don't know what SPNs to setup.

Most recently, I've stumbled across this article which seems to say fly in the face of some other articles:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/01/19/service-principal-name-spn-checklist-for-kerberos-authentication-with-iis-7-0.aspx

Note that it says

> The SPN requirements remain the same as above. You don't have to add
>   SPNs like http/ for the Domain1\Username1
>   unlike in IIS 6.0 (where we had to add an SPN of the form
>   http/ for the Application Pool identity).

So I don't know what's right anymore. I don't know if I need to register HTTP SPNs or HOST SPNs or use the DNS alias or the NetBIOS name, and set them on the PineappleService account or on the VS1 computer account.

I can't tell if when I try things that there's a slow AD replication issue that means I must wait an hour between trial and error.

It's all so complicated now. I've worked as a sysop and dev for 15 years and I sense the end of domains and workstations and rights and policies. It's all gotten too much.

Thanks for your help.

Luke

This is a cross-post with ServerFault which is getting no answers:

https://serverfault.com/questions/417483/serviceprinciplename-setup-for-web-service-on-iis-

Comment: `invoking functions that cause the service (running as PineappleService) to access stuff on the network, fails`.  Are you impersonating the authenticated user and trying to use the authenticated user identity to access the network resources?

Comment: Hi Harvey - no. I'm just calling right out under the App Pool's context, i.e. as PineappleService. So far, when a good error comes back, its UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: It simply means `DOM\PineappleService` doesn't have permissions to access the network resources.  I suggest you to login as `DOM\PineappleService` and run a simple program to prove that this account has the permission to access the resources or not

Comment: Hi Harvey - I've tried. All is fine using RunAs, I'm pretty confident this is an SPN issue. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you are using your client credentials but not your App Pool credentials.  Can you check if you have `<identity impersonate="true" />` set in your web.config?  You should set it to false.